# What's differences between steady-state Kalman filter and Time-varying Kalman filter?

Tags: kalman-filter, steady-state

I understand that the steady-state Kalman filter is more computationally efficient because the noise in a measurement equation and the shock in a state equation have a constant variance over the time period. However, what model should I use if I want to study the effect of a noise shock, which refers to a large shock that was not imaginable?

Should I use a time-varying Kalman filter that allows for the variance of noise to vary? I am faced with this question because I cannot exactly tell the differences between these models and their respective advantages and disadvantages. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "shock"?

Comment: These filters assume that the noise variance is white and constant so if you plan to change this term dramatically then likely that's not an ideal model.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Hi, I meant 'unexpected high variance'.

Comment: @PC1 However, a time-varying Kalman filter allows varying variance of noise right?

Comment: How do you evaluate this varying variance? You will likely need a model, right?

Comment: @PC1 I have my model, I didn't specify here though. I already have data.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question if no information is provided about the variance. The "normal" Kalman filter is using a white noise iid process so it's easy to understand. Maybe your model is better for your use case, maybe not.

Comment: @PC1 Thank you for comments, while answering your questions, I figured out I have to use time-varying KF since I want to show Kalman gain fluctuates due to varying variance of noise. Also, KF does not necessarily assume 'constant' variance. Steady-state KF assumes that constant variance though. Of course, noise should be normally distributed, but the variance can be varying.

Comment: @user14261785 a normal (time varying) Kalman filter can deal with known varying variances. So it won't be able to deal with unexpected high variance of noise optimally.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Thanks! Let me clarify here. What I meant by 'unexpectedly' is that 'noise variance at the current period is unexpectedly high (or low) compared to previous periods'. Of course noise variance in my setting is time-varying. Does it make sense?